# Android Studio Project Structure has changed

Tags: android-studio, structure, project

Usually when I open my Android Studios and I click on new project it then comes up with another page that asks you to enter Application name: etc...Something has changed somewhere for some reason because that doesn't come up. If I click on a recent project it opens up but at the top left hand corner where you can change the view to project, package,  Android etc. Android is no longer in there and the drop down options are now Project, Packages, Scratch, Problems etc. How can I get back the normal view? Or can someone tell me what could have caused this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just restore Studio default layout by Shift+F12

Comment: Hi, that didn't change anything